# Make Width/Height Expand In 3 Directions On Hover

Tags: css

So basically the menu buttons only changes height/width in two directions, and I need to do it three (in both directions left and right, and the bottom).

Here is what it looks like:
http://hijinxnetwork.net/web.html
The CSS:

```
body {
    bakground-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/vjB3x6m.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
.top {
  background-color: #232323;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:40px;
}
.header img {
  width:450px;
  padding-left:650px;
}
.header {
  background-color: #101010;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  height:225px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:40px;
}
.nav {
  width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.nav ul {
  position:relative;
  top:179px;
  left:auto;
  right:auto;
}
.nav li {
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  display:block;
  margin-left:3px;
  margin-right:3px;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:24px;
  background-color: #363636;
  height:50px;
  padding-top:20px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background-color:#a61919;
  height:60px;
  font-size:30px;
}
.nav li a {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

So, if you have any idea on how to change this, that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Do you want resizing button to push adjacent buttons aside while growing or overlay them? Either way what you can do for example is to give the buttons `position:relative` and `left:0`, and on hover `left: -10px`, while making the width slightly bigger to overcompensate left offset [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3q49njs/1/)

Comment: @Pejs I want it to push the other buttons asside. Thanks.

Comment: Than try to add `position: relative` and `left: 0` to your `.nav li` and on `:hover` add for example `left: -10px` and see if that does what you want

Comment: @Pejs Didn't work, sadly

Comment: Worked for me: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/m1tyhap4/). Remember to add negative margin to hover to straighten up margins

Comment: @Pejs The buttons on the left do not move over, though